# Python Printing with a User Input

Tags: python

I need to write a code for printing my name as below by taking the user input for a name. I need to use for and if statements.

Here is an A-Z list of the letters A-Z. I know how to do the input code but I am unsure of how to actually loop it using 'for' and 'if' statements. I have tried to google search for help but nothing has helped. I have already asked this question but have changed my initial work. The code keeps saying syntax error.

```py
    # print A to Z in python for Q7
    print("..######..\n..#....#..\n..######..\n..#....#..\n..#....#..\n\n")

    print("..######..\n..#....#..\n..#####...\n..#....#..\n..######..\n\n")
    print("..######..\n..#.......\n..#.......\n..#.......\n..######..\n\n")

    print("..#####...\n..#....#..\n..#....#..\n..#....#..\n..#####...\n\n")
    print("..######..\n..#.......\n..#####...\n..#.......\n..######..\n\n")

    print("..######..\n..#.......\n..#####...\n..#.......\n..#.......\n\n")

    print("..######..\n..#.......\n..#####...\n..#....#..\n..#####...\n\n")

    print("..#....#..\n..#....#..\n..######..\n..#....#..\n..#....#..\n\n")

    print("..######..\n....##....\n....##....\n....##....\n..######..\n\n")

    print("..######..\n....##....\n....##....\n..#.##....\n..####....\n\n")

    print("..#...#...\n..#..#....\n..##......\n..#..#....\n..#...#...\n\n")

    print("..#.......\n..#.......\n..#.......\n..#.......\n..######..\n\n")

    print("..#....#..\n..##..##..\n..#.##.#..\n..#....#..\n..#....#..\n\n")

    print("..#....#..\n..##...#..\n..#.#..#..\n..#..#.#..\n..#...##..\n\n")

    print("..######..\n..#....#..\n..#....#..\n..#....#..\n..######..\n\n")

    print("..######..\n..#....#..\n..######..\n..#.......\n..#.......\n\n")

    print("..######..\n..#....#..\n..#.#..#..\n..#..#.#..\n..######..\n\n")

    print("..######..\n..#....#..\n..#.##...\n..#...#...\n..#....#..\n\n")

    print("..######..\n..#.......\n..######..\n.......#..\n..######..\n\n")

    print("..######..\n....##....\n....##....\n....##....\n....##....\n\n")

    print("..#....#..\n..#....#..\n..#....#..\n..#....#..\n..######..\n\n")

    print("..#....#..\n..#....#..\n..#....#..\n...#..#...\n....##....\n\n")

    print("..#....#..\n..#....#..\n..#.##.#..\n..##..##..\n..#....#..\n\n")

    print("..#....#..\n...#..#...\n....##....\n...#..#...\n..#....#..\n\n")

    print("..#....#..\n...#..#...\n....##....\n....##....\n....##....\n\n")

    print("..######..\n......#...\n.....#....\n....#.....\n..######..\n\n")
```

For example, entering the name `seymour` would produce this output:

```
seymour
..######..
..#.......
..######..
.......#..
..######..


..######..
..#.......
..#####...
..#.......
..######..


..#....#..
...#..#...
....##....
....##....
....##....


..#....#..
..##..##..
..#.##.#..
..#....#..
..#....#..


..######..
..#....#..
..#....#..
..#....#..
..######..


..#....#..
..#....#..
..#....#..
..#....#..
..######..


..######..
..#....#..
..#.##...
..#...#...
..#....#..
```

I have tried to use 'while' and 'if' statements using the code but it keeps saying syntax error. Below is my code so far.

```py
    name= input('Enter name: ')
    i=0 
    while i<0 len(name):s
    if i== 'A' or 'a' then print("..######..\n..#....#..\n..######..\n..#....#..\n..#....#..\n\n")
    if S[i]= 'B' or 'b' then print("..######..\n..#....#..\n..#####...\n..#....#..\n..######..\n\n")
    if S[i]= 'C' or 'c' then print("..######..\n..#.......\n..#.......\n..#.......\n..######..\n\n")
    if S[i]= 'D' or 'd' then print("..#####...\n..#....#..\n..#....#..\n..#....#..\n..#####...\n\n")
    if S[i]= 'E' or 'e' then print("..######..\n..#.......\n..#####...\n..#.......\n..######..\n\n")
    if S[i]= 'F' or 'f' then print("..######..\n..#.......\n..#####...\n..#.......\n..#.......\n\n")
    if S[i]= 'G' or 'g' then print("..######..\n..#.......\n..#####...\n..#....#..\n..#####...\n\n")
    if S[i]= 'H' or 'h' then print("..#....#..\n..#....#..\n..######..\n..#....#..\n..#....#..\n\n")
    if S[i]= 'I' or 'i' then print("..######..\n....##....\n....##....\n....##....\n..######..\n\n")
    if S[i]= 'J' or 'j' then print("..######..\n....##....\n....##....\n..#.##....\n..####....\n\n")
    if S[i]= 'K' or 'k' then print("..#...#...\n..#..#....\n..##......\n..#..#....\n..#...#...\n\n")
    if S[i]= 'L' or 'l' then print("..#.......\n..#.......\n..#.......\n..#.......\n..######..\n\n")
    if S[i]= 'M' or 'm' then print("..#....#..\n..##..##..\n..#.##.#..\n..#....#..\n..#....#..\n\n")
    if S[i]= 'N' or 'n' then print("..#....#..\n..##...#..\n..#.#..#..\n..#..#.#..\n..#...##..\n\n")
    if S[i]= 'O' or 'o' then print("..######..\n..#....#..\n..#....#..\n..#....#..\n..######..\n\n")
    if S[i]= 'P' or 'p' then print("..######..\n..#....#..\n..######..\n..#.......\n..#.......\n\n")
    if S[i]= 'Q' or 'q' then print("..######..\n..#....#..\n..#.#..#..\n..#..#.#..\n..######..\n\n")
    if S[i]= 'R' or 'r' then print("..######..\n..#....#..\n..#.##...\n..#...#...\n..#....#..\n\n")
    if S[i]= 'S' or 's' then print("..######..\n..#.......\n..######..\n.......#..\n..######..\n\n")
    if S[i]= 'T' or 't' then print("..######..\n....##....\n....##....\n....##....\n....##....\n\n")
    if S[i]= 'U' or 'u' then print("..#....#..\n..#....#..\n..#....#..\n..#....#..\n..######..\n\n")
    if S[i]= 'V' or 'v' then print("..#....#..\n..#....#..\n..#....#..\n...#..#...\n....##....\n\n")
    if S[i]= 'W' or 'w' then print("..#....#..\n..#....#..\n..#.##.#..\n..##..##..\n..#....#..\n\n")
    if S[i]= 'X' or 'x' then print("..#....#..\n...#..#...\n....##....\n...#..#...\n..#....#..\n\n")
    if S[i]= 'Y' or 'y' then print("..#....#..\n...#..#...\n....##....\n....##....\n....##....\n\n")
    if S[i]= 'Z' or 'z' then print("..######..\n......#...\n.....#....\n....#.....\n..######..\n\n")
```

```
  File "program.py", line 3
    while i<0 len(name):s
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This is what comes up. I tried to fix it, but then every other line comes up with the same thing.

Comment: Have you removed the 's' after the colon?

Comment: @saltchicken yes sorry, i must of accidentally pressed on it. However, this is not the cause of my problem :)

Comment: if/then is not valid python. Also you are using or incorrectly. Try `if S[i] == 'B': print('## whatever')`. Convert the whole string to upper case before the loop, so you havent got to try to match both cases.

Comment: The eror message shows you (approximately) where the error is. Namely, you are missing a colon after your while statement. The command should be `while i < len(name):` (note the colon). You also need to remove the `0` and the `s` from the line. Then you need to indent all the `if` s that follow the `while` statement. You also do not handle the `or`s correctly in your `if` statements. (This is a logic error, not a syntax error.) The previous comment points out that `then` does not belong in Python. You have a lot of learning to do about Python!

Comment: [here](https://ideone.com/ISvaFi) is how it could be done by switching out the chain of ifs for a dict, which maps the chars to what is to be printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if condition should be if S[i] == 'G' or ***S[i] ==*** 'g'

New code:

```
name = input('Enter name: ')

for char in name:
    if char == 'A' or char == 'a': print("..######..\n..#....#..\n..######..\n..#....#..\n..#....#..\n\n")
    elif char == 'B' or char == 'b': print("..######..\n..#....#..\n..#####...\n..#....#..\n..######..\n\n")
    elif char == 'C' or char == 'c': print("..######..\n..#.......\n..#.......\n..#.......\n..######..\n\n")
    elif char == 'D' or char == 'd': print("..#####...\n..#....#..\n..#....#..\n..#....#..\n..#####...\n\n")
    elif char == 'E' or char == 'e': print("..######..\n..#.......\n..#####...\n..#.......\n..######..\n\n")
    elif char == 'F' or char == 'f': print("..######..\n..#.......\n..#####...\n..#.......\n..#.......\n\n")
    elif char == 'G' or char == 'g': print("..######..\n..#.......\n..#####...\n..#....#..\n..#####...\n\n")
    elif char == 'H' or char == 'h': print("..#....#..\n..#....#..\n..######..\n..#....#..\n..#....#..\n\n")
    elif char == 'I' or char == 'i': print("..######..\n....##....\n....##....\n....##....\n..######..\n\n")
    elif char == 'J' or char == 'j': print("..######..\n....##....\n....##....\n..#.##....\n..####....\n\n")
    elif char == 'K' or char == 'k': print("..#...#...\n..#..#....\n..##......\n..#..#....\n..#...#...\n\n")
    elif char == 'L' or char == 'l': print("..#.......\n..#.......\n..#.......\n..#.......\n..######..\n\n")
    elif char == 'M' or char == 'm': print("..#....#..\n..##..##..\n..#.##.#..\n..#....#..\n..#....#..\n\n")
    elif char == 'N' or char == 'n': print("..#....#..\n..##...#..\n..#.#..#..\n..#..#.#..\n..#...##..\n\n")
    elif char == 'O' or char == 'o': print("..######..\n..#....#..\n..#....#..\n..#....#..\n..######..\n\n")
    elif char == 'P' or char == 'p': print("..######..\n..#....#..\n..######..\n..#.......\n..#.......\n\n")
    elif char == 'Q' or char == 'q': print("..######..\n..#....#..\n..#.#..#..\n..#..#.#..\n..######..\n\n")
    elif char == 'R' or char == 'r': print("..######..\n..#....#..\n..#.##...\n..#...#...\n..#....#..\n\n")
    elif char == 'S' or char == 's': print("..######..\n..#.......\n..######..\n.......#..\n..######..\n\n")
    elif char == 'T' or char == 't': print("..######..\n....##....\n....##....\n....##....\n....##....\n\n")
    elif char == 'U' or char == 'u': print("..#....#..\n..#....#..\n..#....#..\n..#....#..\n..######..\n\n")
    elif char == 'V' or char == 'v': print("..#....#..\n..#....#..\n..#....#..\n...#..#...\n....##....\n\n")
    elif char == 'W' or char == 'w': print("..#....#..\n..#....#..\n..#.##.#..\n..##..##..\n..#....#..\n\n")
    elif char == 'X' or char == 'x': print("..#....#..\n...#..#...\n....##....\n...#..#...\n..#....#..\n\n")
    elif char == 'Y' or char == 'y': print("..#....#..\n...#..#...\n....##....\n....##....\n....##....\n\n")
    elif char == 'Z' or char == 'z': print("..######..\n......#...\n.....#....\n....#.....\n..######..\n\n")
```